# Why python3 pip module found the python2 libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I was trying a simple snippet that upgrades all my pip-installed packages via the following script:

```
# pip_upgrade.py
import pip
from subprocess import call
black_list = ['scipy', 'PySide', 'python-apt']
failed_list = []
for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    dist_name = dist.project_name
    if dist_name in black_list:
        continue
    rc = call(("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name).split(), shell=False) 
    if rc != 0:
        failed_list.append(dist_name)
print('=' * 80)
print('\n'.join(failed_list))
```

And I was hoping that this would work for both python2 and python3, that is to say:

```
sudo python2 pip_upgrade.py
sudo python3 pip_upgrade.py
```

However, I found that when trying `python3`(python3.4), the output is like below:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: Send2Trash in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...

...

Requirement already up-to-date: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up... 

...
```

This indicates that *python3* version still tries to list *python2* libraries.

I also unset PYTHONPATH, and the list `sys.path` includes nothing about python2 when using python3, but still the same issue.

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call

```
rc = call(("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name).split(), shell=False)
```

is a system call that runs the default "pip" on your system

so you'll get exactly the same behavior if you run this line with python2 or python3.

What you should do instead is install the two versions of pip (pip for python2, and pip for python3).

Then call `python2-pip install stuff` to install on your python2 installation, and `python3-pip install stuff` to install it on your python3 installation.

You seem to be using linux. So just install the two pip packages with your package manager. Depending on your distro, pip for python2 is called pip, pip2, pip-python2 or python2-pip, while pip for python3 can be called pip, pip3, pip-python3 or python3-pip.

Run

```
pip --version
```

to check which version of python the pip script refers to.

Comment: Quite SILLY question. Sorry I didn't notice that!